# Control may reach end of non-void function ERROR

Tags: c, xcode

I can't seem to find the issue with this function. I am relatively new to C and am trying to understand why this function won't... function. I use Xcode and end with a "Control may reach end of non-void function" warning. Thank you for the help

```
int call_shooting(char p1[10][10], char p2[10][10], char p3[10][10], char p4[10][10], char hit_miss[2], char data[5][2], int coin, int hit_miss_storage[2][128], int coord_storage[4][128])
{
    int j = 0, k = 0, f = 0;

    if (coin == 1)
    {
        while (j == 0)
        {
            shoot(p1, p2, p3, p4, 1, hit_miss, k, hit_miss_storage, coord_storage);
            check_sink(p1, data, 0);

            j = check_win_loss(p1);
            if (j == 1)
            {
                system("cls");
                print_board(p2, p4);
                hit_miss_ships(hit_miss);
                sunken_ships(data);
                printf("\nYou won!!!\n\n");
                return 1;
                break;
            }
            shoot(p1, p2, p3, p4, 0, hit_miss, k, hit_miss_storage, coord_storage);
            check_sink(p2, data, 1);

            j = check_win_loss(p2);
            if (j == 1)
            {
                system("cls");
                print_board(p2, p4);
                hit_miss_ships(hit_miss);
                sunken_ships(data);
                printf("\nYou lost!!!\n\n");
                return 0;
                break;
            }
            system("cls");

            print_board(p2, p4);
            hit_miss_ships(hit_miss);
            sunken_ships(data);

            k++;
            f++;
        }
    }
    else if (coin == 0)
    {
        while (j == 0)
        {
            shoot(p1, p2, p3, p4, 0, hit_miss, k, hit_miss_storage, coord_storage);
            check_sink(p2, data, 1);


            j = check_win_loss(p2);
            if (j == 1)
            {
                system("cls");
                print_board(p2, p4);
                hit_miss_ships(hit_miss);
                sunken_ships(data);
                printf("\nYou lost!!!\n\n");
                return 0;
                break;
            }
            system("cls");
            print_board(p2, p4);
            hit_miss_ships(hit_miss);
            sunken_ships(data);

            shoot(p1, p2, p3, p4, 1, hit_miss, k, hit_miss_storage, coord_storage);
            check_sink(p1, data, 0);


            j = check_win_loss(p1);
            if (j == 1)
            {
                system("cls");
                print_board(p2, p4);
                hit_miss_ships(hit_miss);
                sunken_ships(data);
                printf("\nYou won!!!\n\n");
                return 1;
                break;
            }
            system("cls");

            print_board(p2, p4);
            hit_miss_ships(hit_miss);
            sunken_ships(data);

            k++;
            f++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the compiler is confused by the dead code (break after return) that you have there? Anyhow, that warning comes from an analysis of all possible code paths and if you created a [mcve], I'm pretty sure you would at some point have found the answer why your function sometimes doesn't return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler sees to leave the `while` loop if `j!=0`. There is no return value of the method if eg `j=check_win_loss(...)` was assigned any value other than `1`.

Typical C solution: return an error Code at the end of the method, e.g. `return -1`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler sees that if `coin` is neither `0` nor `1` then the function ends without returning anything.

If you know for sure that this function will not be called with `coin` being anything else than `0` or `1`, then you could replace your `if (coin == 1) {...} else if (coin == 0) {...}` with a simple  `if (coin == 1) {...} else {...}`.

---

Edit:

There is also the problem that the compiler sees that if `j` becomes something else than `0` or `1` inside either one of your `while` loops, then the function leaves that loop and returns without returning anything.

You have at least two options to fix that:

- Change all the `if (j == 1)` to `if (j != 0)`.

or

- Add `return -1;` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0):

To you `coin` and `check_win_loss` can only be/return `0` or `1`, but the compiler doesn't know that. If `coin == 2` or `check_win_loss` `return`ed `3`, you would exit the function without ever doing a `return`.

Solution: Try making their (return) type bool and see if it fixes it. Otherwise, consider returning an error value at the end of the function or doing an `assert(0 && "This shouldn't ever happen");` to pacify the compiler.

Keep in mind, this is merely a warning, not an error (but if they actually return something different than `0` or `1` and you exit without a return value, but read it anyway, behavior is undefined, which is way worse).